# Updated *.drl but the changes are not effecting

Tags: java, drools

when the *.drl file is read by the compiler or which line of code is reading *.drl and i want to update the *.drl when the program is in execution wheater i get effected to the program?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    KnowledgeBase kbase = createKnowledgeBase();
    StatefulKnowledgeSession session = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    Account account = new Account();
    account.setBalance(99);
    account.setId("N1");
    Account account2 = new Account();
    account2.setBalance(12);
    account2.setId("N2");
    session.insert(account);
    session.insert(account2);

    session.fireAllRules();
}

private static KnowledgeBase createKnowledgeBase() throws InterruptedException {
    KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory
            .newKnowledgeBuilder();
    //File accountRules = new File("rules.drl");
    System.out.println("**Before Thread****");
    Thread.sleep(50000);
    System.out.println("***After Theread****");
    builder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("com/iton/rules/rules.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
    if (builder.hasErrors()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(builder.getErrors().toString());
    }

    KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    knowledgeBase.addKnowledgePackages(builder.getKnowledgePackages());
    return knowledgeBase;
}
```

}

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, given the code above, if you change the .drl file, you need to run the `createKnowledgeBase()` method again.

Comment: The program is in runing state i have changed *.drl it should get reflected to the program other wise y to use drools

Comment: If you want Drools to automatically reload DRL at runtime, then you need to change your code to use Knowledge Agents to manage the knowledge base:  http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.6.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch02.html#d0e2239